# Unable to run my Angular 2 application when using Event Emitters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, rxjs

I've run into an issue where my application will no longer load after adding a service that utilizes Event Emitters.  The error I get is as follows:

```
"SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
Evaluating http://localhost:3000/node_modules/angular2/ts/src/facade/async
Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js" angular2-polyfills.js:138:14

SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
```

My Main.ts file where I do the application bootstrapping looks like this:

```
import {bootstrap} from "angular2/platform/browser"
import {provide} from "angular2/core";
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from "angular2/router"

import {AppComponent} from "./app.component"
import {LocalStorageService} from "./core/localstorage.service";
import {PersistenceService} from "./core/persistence.service";

bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    LocalStorageService,
    provide(PersistenceService, {useExisting: LocalStorageService})
]);
```

The service where I'm using Event Emitters looks like this:

```
import {Injectable, Output} from "angular2/core";
import {EventEmitter} from "../../node_modules/angular2/ts/src/facade/async";

@Injectable()
export class GlobalActionsService {
    @Output() saveSettings: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
    @Output() loadSettings: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

    doSave() {
        this.saveSettings.emit(null);
    }

    doLoad() {
        this.loadSettings.emit(null);
    }

}
```

And finally, my index.html looks like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Set the base href for routing -->
        <base href="/">

        <title>MyApp</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- 1. Load stylesheets -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./public/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./public/css/custom.css">

        <!-- 2. Load libraries -->
        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>

        <!-- 3. Configure SystemJS -->
        <script>
            System.config({
                packages: {
                    app: {
                        format: 'register',
                        defaultExtension: 'js'
                    }
                }
            });
            System.import('app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));
        </script>
    </head>

    <!-- 4. Display the application -->
    <body>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if my problem is related to how I'm bootstrapping the app, my usage of Event Emitters, or something else entirely...if anyone can shed some light as to what the problem might be here, it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import the `EventEmitter` this way (from the core module of Angular2):

```
import {Injectable, Output, EventEmitter} from "angular2/core";
```